# Why is my innerHTML change colour not working with javascript keydown?

Tags: javascript

I've created a site with several buttons and the buttons can be clicked by mouse or activated by keyboard (each button has a unique letter as its `innerHTML` to be pressed) and when that unique letter is pressed by the user on the keyboard, the button will be activated. Activated buttons would play a unique sound each and change the `innerHTML` color to orange. All works except when keyboard is pressed, the `innerHTML` doesn't change colour on screen (in summary: both `keydown` and mouse clicks make sound but only mouse click changes colour). What is wrong with my code?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
// Detecting clicks works
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.style.color = "orange"
        makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
    }
  );
}


// Detecting keydown works but not change color
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var button = event.target;
  var buttonInnerHTML = button.innerHTML;
  button.style.color = "orange";
  makeSound(event.key);
})


// makeSound function works
function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kickbass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickbass.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}
```

And here is my html body:

```
<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

<script src="index2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can we also please have just the minimal, dom/html body this is working on?

Comment: your need reference the event.key back to the correct button to apply a style to it ie pressing `w` links to index `0` which you can then do `document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].style.color` etc, prob needs rewriting taking that into consideration, also look into arrays of objects and loops, lots of DRY breaking

Comment: Hey, argonx: Thanks for adding the HTML, I've added an answer below, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are binding your `keypress` to the document with `document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {...}`.  And then immediately in that function, you are trying to define the button with `event.target`.  This will not work, because `keypress` is globally-applied here (it is bound to the `document`).  How does it know which button to highlight if you just press a key?

Well, you can have it use event to get the key pressed, then use the key pressed in a class selector of the button...

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName(String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase())[0];
  var buttonInnerHTML = button.innerHTML;
  button.style.color = "orange";
  makeSound(event.key);
})
```

So, I merely changed the definition of button from `event.target` to `document.getElementsByClassName(String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase())[0];`.

You already have the class defined in the element you want to affect here, so, it should automatically work out of the box...

```
<button class="w drum">w</button>
```

[**Full working demo online.**](https://jsbin.com/zocotat/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the orange text styling to the document and not to the individual buttons when you press a letter as `event.target` returns the element the event applied to.

You probably want to change the line `button.style.color = "orange";` to something like `document.getElementsByClassName("w drum")[0].style.color = "orange";` and instead put it under the case it applies to e.g `case "w":`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding `keydown` event to `document`, add `keydown` event to every buttons, like you are doing with `click` event.